# How to save predictions for each evaluation by Trainer in transformers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

During training, I make prediction and evaluate my model at the end of each epoch. I want to save the prediction results every time I evaluate my model. How to achieve this using Trainer?

Using the code here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/summarization/run_summarization.py can only save the prediction results for the last epoch.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters which interest you can be found in the `Seq2SeqTrainingArguments`, which contains information on how the actual training should take place for your model ([doc](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Seq2SeqTrainingArguments)). These TrainingArguments are passed to the main you referred to at line [298](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/summarization/run_summarization.py#L298).

You should add the following parameters during its initialization:

```py
training_arguments = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
        ...
        evaluation_strategy="epoch", # Frequency of evaluating
        logging_strategy="epoch", # Frequency of logging to file
        save_strategy="epoch" # Frequency of saving checkpoints
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, these arguments only allow to save model checkpoints and evaluation metric results, but can not save the prediction results for each evaluation. For example, in a translation task, evaluation metric such as BLEU for each evaluation will be saved, while the translation results will only be saved once when the training is compeleted. I want to save the translation results for each evaluation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I see, ty for detailing! 
Reading the code, it would seem the TrainingArgument parameter `predict_with_generate` could help, did you give it a try?